# Removing mouse listener from animation

Tags: animate

I'm trying to create an animation using the `animateinline` environment from the `animate` package. More precisely, I want to remove the mouse listener from the animation itself, so that it is controlled exclusively by the media buttons I place.

(In other words, I'm trying to make clicking on the "A" or "B" do nothing, or, ideally, make it just select them as if they were normal text.)

I've tried placing a `tikzpicture` above the entire thing, but that didn't work. <s>I also haven't found anything in the `animate` package documentation regarding this.</s>

The `mediabutton`s are needed to later control multiple `animateinline` environments with the same button, which to my knowledge the standard `controls` option cannot do.

Any help is much appreciated.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[
    label=myAnim,
    autoplay = false,
    step = true,
    loop = true,
    autoresume = false,
    autopause = false
]{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{animateinline}

\mediabutton[
    jsaction={
        % ensures frameNum stays within range
        if(anim.myAnim.frameNum > 0){
            anim.myAnim.frameNum--
        }
    }
]{\fbox{\strut Previous}}
\mediabutton[
    jsaction={
        % ensures frameNum stays within range
        if(anim.myAnim.frameNum < anim.myAnim.numFrames - 1){
            anim.myAnim.frameNum++
        }
    }
]{\fbox{\strut Next}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add the `nomouse` option. It's described on page 8 of [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf).

Comment: I'm so embarrassed I didn't see that in the documentation, I should've read more carefully. This solves my problem completely. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well I can see from your question that you put quite some effort in, so that lets me assume that you also already put some effort in reading the manual. IMHO there's no shame in missing something in any manual and therefore asking here, only in asking when you haven't even checked the manual. Off-topic: I believe this is your first question so let met [Welcome you to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The closing reason is a bit weird. Isn't there something like "was answered in the comments" or similar available as a closing reason?

Comment: @AlexG oops there is? I'm sorry I can't seem to find my way in the mobile app, I thought I added "This question is solved in the comments." in some menu, but apparently it does not show up here.

Comment: @Max This specific close reason doesn't seem to exist, but I read it before in connection with another question. There is a sub-item when closing as off-topic that can be checked and be extended with a comment. I think this was used. But don't worry. I just thought it would sound a bit more specific and friendly.

Comment: @AlexG I agree, so hereby: I voted to close this question as off-topic, because it is solved in the comments.